# Text field is enlarged when hidding other widgets in stackview swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have added a stack view in table view cell, I have added a textField, a textView, and others views and their subviews(images labels), I have added buttons of respective widget, when I click the button, the respective widget should appear and other widgets should be hidden but the widget that appear is enlarged on whole stack view, I want the widget should occupy its original size and other size of hidden widget should be empty.

Note: I have added some UIvIEWs and textfield and Textview in a stack view, now i want to show only one view or TextField or Textview based on what Button I click then stack view should hide other widgets (like remaining views or text field or textview except what was clicked), it does fine here but the error is the selected or showed widget is enlarged in size and occupy all spcae of other widgets which are hidden

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var Cell : UITableViewCell?
        Cell = firstTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell")! as UITableViewCell
        if widgetInstockArray.count == 0 && labelInstockArray.isEmpty {
            print("no textFields in instock")
        }
        else {
            print("widget process i in winstock loop")
            let i = widgetInstockArray[indexPath.row]
                if i.contains(wTextField)  {
                    print("textField was placed")
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = false
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = true
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = true
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = true
                    Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = true
                    Cell?.textLabel?.text = labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
                   }
                else {
                    print("no textField exist")
            }
            if i.contains(wCamView) {
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = false
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.textLabel?.text = labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
                print("nothing cam")
            }
            if i.contains(wTextView) {
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = false
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = true
                let tvLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 30))
                tvLabel.text = "You title"
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.addSubview(tvLabel)
                Cell?.textLabel?.text =  labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
                }
              else {
                }

            if i.contains(wCheckBox) {
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = false
                Cell?.textLabel?.text =  labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
            }
            if i.contains(wDateView) {
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = false
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.textLabel?.text =  labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
            }

            if i.contains(wSignView) {
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6)?.isHidden = false
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(9)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(12)?.isHidden = true
                Cell?.textLabel?.text =  labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
            }
            print("could not add widgets")
        }

    Cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    return Cell!
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did u solve this? Not understood clearly.

Comment: @McDonal_11 please have a look at hirarchy of view in images and code, i am unable to solve this, please help me to solve this.

Comment: I read ur question. But, unable to understood

Comment: @McDonal_11 I have added some UIvIEWa and textfield Textview in a stack view , now i want to show only one view or TextField or Textview based on what Button I click then stack view should hide other widgets (like remaining views or text field or textview except what was clicked), it does but the error is the selected or showed widget is enlarged in size and occupy all spcae of other widgets which are hidden

Comment: That enlargement will happen. BCos, that is UIStackView property. If suppose, stackview height is 100, you have 4 UIViews inside UIStackView which has equal spacing and vertical axis, then, u r trying to hide two views means, remaining two UIView height will be automatically increase to 50 from 25..

Comment: Hope u understood above logic??

Comment: @McDonal_11 i got it, but how can i overcome this, as i want the widget should occupy their original size like 25 and rest of the height should be escaped

Comment: If I am trying to hide, view1 and view 3, then, view2 and view4 will come up with same 25 height ??

Comment: I update my sample answer for your issue. Kindly check it once.

Comment: Did u try ?????

Comment: @McDonal_11 I am trying but i am unable to give constraints to UIStackView as, top, left, right as 15 and Height as 100.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty view at the bottom that will fill the empty space if you don't have anything to display in the blank area.

As shown in below screens

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add Four `UIView`to UIStackView and give constraints to `UIStackView` as, top, left, right as 15 and Height as 100.

Then, click that StackView's Height Constraints, and Change priority to 750, then, Normal line is changed to Dotted Line [Image 1].

**Image 1**:

[image]

Then, StackView axis should be vertical and alignment and distribution will be Fill and spacing as 10 [Image 2].

**Image 2:**

[image]

Then, now with `UIView`.

You have to click each and every view and set Height Constraints for this. Only height constraints should add [Image 3].

**Image 3**

[image]

Then, if you try to run, you will get output what you need. Try sample, then go with your project.

Comment: I am unable to give constraints to UIStackView as, top, left, right as 15 and Height as 100.

Comment: U have used, UIStackView in side tableviewcell ??

Comment: I have use stackview inside the cellof table view

Comment: yes.. you can add constraints, top bottom left and height.

Comment: I have added but now widgtes are not appearing but white cells are appearning with placeholders